# Alternative to Glimpse for ASP.Net 2.0 and 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net, glimpse

I have a project that I am forced to use ASP.Net 2.0, is there an alternative to Glimpse that gives me all or some of the data that Glimpse can give?

The main things I'm looking for are :

- Session values
- Request values like Path info, Query string, and so on

Comment: You could also vote for the Glimpse team to add support at their UserVoice site: http://getglimpse.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ASP.NET Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which has been around since the early days of ASP.NET.